# formating string in java based on positions

Tags: java

I have a string containing many words.
The words has to be displayed based on the positions.

Example,

```
   String str = "Australia Canberra Adellide ";
```

The above string should be,

Australia should start at 0 and end at 20

Canberra should start at 20 and end at 30

Adellide should start at 30 and end at 50

This i will be displaying in a jtextarea

Are there any formatter available in java? or padding should be used?

Comment: Break it at space into three separate strings and use `String.format` with fixed width for each string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pad strings with [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) with the `%-ns` format specifier.

```
String s = String.format("%-20s%-10s%-20s","Hello","to","you.");
// "Hello               to        you.                "
```

If you want to intersperse letters between individual letters, your best bet is probably a simple regular expression (i.e., `s.replaceAll(".", "$0 ")`).

Answer (score 1):

The example is hard to follow: Canberra and 'Adellide' are the same length, so how come Canberra only gets 10 characters, but Adellide gets 20?

Anyway, could you use a [formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)?  If needed, you can [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the input String containing the list.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
String str = String.format("%20s%10s%20s", "Australia", "Canberra", "Adellide");
```

Or if you want the left-justified:

```
String str = String.format("%-20s%-10s%-20s", "Australia", "Canberra", "Adellide");
```